# Multiple Handlers attached to one event: How to detach only one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In this module I'm working on I have a listener to a 'resize' event  in the window. Every time the module is ran, I need to check if there's already a listener registered to that event and detach it, in order to avoid unwanted behavior, memory leaks and etc.

So far so good, but, in this application we are working on, chances are that some handlers are already attached to the 'resize' event and I can't call `$(window).off('resize')`, as this would flush all the other event handlers previously registered by other plugins or modules.

Being that said, I would like to know if there's a way to identify my handler and only detach things that I have registered myself. How  do I set an identifier to my event handler in order to be referenced in the `.off()` function?

Any help would be nice.

Comment: use off to remove all handlers and just write new event after it..

Comment: use namespaced event to bind/unbind it or use a referenced handler

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I can't do that because I would remove the other handlers this way. I need to remove only the event handlers that I have attached myself;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here 2 different suggestions. You can either give a namespace to your event or pass a none anonymous function when binding.

## Example when using namespace :

```
$(window).on('resize.event1', function(){});
$(window).on('resize.event2', function(){});

//Only turn off event 2
$(window).off('resize.event2');
```

jQuery allow you to identify your event. This behaviour is called namespace. The current event and the event name must be separate by a dot. In that case, i am binding 2 resize event (left side of the dot), one with the name `event1` and the other with `event2`.

By identifying the event, you can remove (or trigger) single event when an object have multiple of the same event.

```
$(window).trigger('resize'); //Trigger both;
$(window).trigger('resize.event2'); //Trigger event2;
```

## Example using named functions :

```
$(window).on('resize', function1);
$(window).on('resize', function2);

//Only turn off event 2
$(window).off('resize', function2);
```

Associating a none anonymous function allow you to remove the event if the passed function match the current event function. Because `function2 === function2`, only the second function will be remove since `function1 !== function2`!

Comment: i am not able to get it what you are saying nee elaboration

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Updated, hope that help!

Answer (score 1):

If you use named handlers (as opposed to anonymous functions) you can pass the name of the handler to `off` to remove just that one (http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
function flash() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}

$( "body" ).off( "click", "#theone", flash )
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this-

```
$(window).off('resize.myCustomEvent');
```

and vice versa to attach it