# jquery on hander to specific function while passing in event

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, event-handling

I'm trying to pass an event to a jquery on keypress handler, but since it's on the document, I want to be a very specific handler because there are multiple instances, of the object using this, on the page. also, I'm using coffeescript

so...

```
  keyPress: (e)->
    # handle key event

  $(document).on 'keypress', (e)=>
    @keyPress e
```

won't work, because the I don't want it to necessarily work for all instances at once.

what I need is something like

```
   $(document).on 'keypress', @keyPress(event)
```

while passing in the event so I can get the keyCode.

I also need this so I can turn it off, if I want, without affecting any other instances

```
   $(document).off 'keypress', @keypress
```

I'm sure the answer is much more simple than I realize.
thanks for the help

EDIT: (maybe this was unclear)

In short, I have multiple carousels on a page and I need to be able to set one of the carousels to respond to key events (left, right)

ideally it would be nice if I could focus on a carousel and use the keys to navigate then, but if that's not possible then just having 1 carousel respond to keys is fine.

the problem comes in when multiple carousels are on the page, the first carousel sets the listener on, and the next one turns it off, or they both turn it on and both carousels move when a key is pressed

EDIT2:
  I think I was looking the .on() version of

```
    $(document).keypress @keyEvents.bind(@)
```

EDIT3:
  I think I'm STILL looking for the .on version, because I also need to be able to turn it off

Comment: I'm not quite sure to understand, but don't you want only `$(document).on 'keypress.customName', @keyPress.bind(this)` and `$(document).off 'keypress.customName'`. I'm not used to coffe, so i may have messed up the bind part.

Comment: So you have a bunch of things bound to keypress events on `document` but you only want one of them to be called? Or do you want to be able to add and remove them individually?

Comment: what's the keypress.customName?  how does that work?  not sure I've ever seen that before

Comment: @Gambai refer to my answer about [jquery event name space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570797/javascript-jquery-multiple-handlers-attached-to-one-event-how-to-detach-onl) or the [doc itself](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

Comment: that's cool!  but not sure that helps me since I'm not firing the event.  how would I namespace the fired keyEvent so that I can namespace the handled keyEvent