# How to disconnect the current event only in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following event:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() { 
    // do stuff
});
```

At the completion of this event, I want to disconnect it.  I can do `$(document).off('scroll');`, but that will disconnect all the `scroll` events (there are several) on the page.

How do I disconnect just this one event?

Comment: Either use namespace or store the specific event handler, then use it in `off` call.

Comment: A scroll event is a one tick motion. The next tick will be another scroll event - do you really want to halt the event for one tick?

Comment: That might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570797/javascript-jquery-multiple-handlers-attached-to-one-event-how-to-detach-onl/23570844

Comment: `$(this).off('scroll')` ?

Comment: @kabanus What do u mean by one tick?  Meaning 1 instruction of the CPU?

Comment: No, I mean every step the scrollbar moves. I think every pixel.

Comment: You'd better go using Event namespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the call back and put it into its own function, then you can remove it.

```
function doScroll(){
  // Do stuff
}

// Add the function
$(document).on('scroll', doScroll);

// Remove the function
$(document).off('scroll', doScroll);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove a specific handler using `off()`, you'll need to pass a reference to the handler, so simply declare your handler function and pass the reference to both `on()` and `off()`:

```
function scrollHandler() {
    // do stuff
}

$(document).on('scroll', scrollHandler);
$(document).off('scroll', scrollHandler);
```

> The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on(). See the discussion of delegated and directly bound events on that page for more information. Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 1):

> *How do I disconnect just this one event?*

by **.namespacing** it!

```
$(document).on({
    "scroll.myNamespace" : function() { 
         // do stuff
    }
});
```

than at some point you can either

```
$(document).off("scroll.myNamespace");
```

or all your namespaced events (if you have more of them, like i.e: `scroll.myNamespace`, `click.myNamespace` etc...)

```
$(document).off(".myNamespace");
```

### Example: how to off a namespaced event

```js
$(document).on({
  "scroll.teapot": function() {
    console.log("TEAPOT!")
  },
  scroll: function() {
    console.log("scroll")
  }
});

$("#offTeapot").on({
  click: function() {
    $(document).off(".teapot"); // off every ".teapot" namespaced event
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 400vh;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="offTeapot">OFF TEAPOTS</button>

<h1>SCROLL!!!!!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting it specifically?

```
$(document).on('scroll', '#yourId', function(){

}).off('scroll', '#yourId', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setup a global flag for one time usage:

```
var doThis = true;

$(document).on('scroll', function() { 
    if(doThis){
        // do stuff
        doThis = false;
    }
});
```